# Unexpected access rights of a file

Tags: linux, c, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using linux as a subsystem in windows .

I do have a problem when creating a file via bash terminal .
If I run the command `touch foo.txt` then `ls -l foo.txt`. All the access rights will be activated and cannot be changed .

```
-rwxrwxrwx foo.txt
```

Is there a solution for this ?

Also tried to write a C Program that creates a file with the 0750 rights but still the same problem :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  umask(0);
  int fd = open("foo.txt", O_RDONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0750);
  if(fd < 0) perror("foo.txt");
  close(fd);
}
```

After compiling the program :

```
-rwxrwxrwx foo.txt
```

BTW it works correctly when using linux on a virtual machine

Comment: In which directory are you creating this file? is it on the local (WSL) filesystem or on the host (Windows) filesystem?

Comment: I just realized that . So creating folders on windows causes some problems ?

Comment: Windows doesn't support the same type of file permission attributes that Linux does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this WSL doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/file-permissions) for information on how permissions map between Windows drives and WSL.  By default, the Windows permissions for the file are what you'll see, and chmod really doesn't have much effect.

But the drives *can* be mounted with metadata support, and WSL will then apply permissions found in the metadata instead of the Windows permissions.  This allows WSL to map Linux permissions on files on Windows drives.

To automatically mount your Windows drives with metadata support:

- Edit or create `/etc/wsl.conf` in your WSL instance
- Add the following lines:

  ```
  [automount]
  enabled = true
  options = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11"
  ```
- Exit your WSL instance
- Terminate the WSL instance using `wsl --terminate <distroname>` from PowerShell or cmd.
- Restart the WSL instance

You should then find that a `touch` results in `.rw-r--r--`, and your code results in the expected `.rwxr-x---` (750).

Tested and confirmed (including your test app) on my WSL2 / Ubuntu 20.04 instance, at least.

Also note that WSL2 performance on Windows drives is really abysmal when compared to WSL1. If you are going to be doing anything file intensive on that drive, use a WSL1 instance if at all possible. Or just stick to the ext4 fs on WSL2.